# Marcar container do checklist e executar JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou apanhando muito no JavaScript, já tentei de diversas formas mas não estou conseguindo...

Tenho uma estrutura assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que quando o primeiro checkbox for marcado, ele faça a multiplicação do primeiro preço com a primeira quantidade. E quando for desmarcado ele zere a multiplicação. Vice versa para os outros checklists.

As quantidades de linhas são fixas, serão sempre essas.
No final fazer a soma de todos os valores e somar o total.

o meu código PHP está assim:

```html
<table id="table1" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Preço</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
   <th>Subtotal</th>
   <th></th>
    </tr>
  
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query2['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco"><?php echo $linha_query2['preco']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt2" id="qt2" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub2" id="sub2" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="ch2"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query3['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco"><?php echo $linha_query3['preco']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt3" id="qt3" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub3" id="sub3" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ch3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query4['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco"><?php echo $linha_query4['preco']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt4" id="qt4" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub4" id="sub4" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch4" value="ch4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query5['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco"><?php echo $linha_query5['preco']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt5" id="qt5" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub5" id="sub5" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch5" value="ch5"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query6['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco"><?php echo $linha_query6['preco']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt6" id="qt6" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub6" id="sub6" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch6" value="ch6"></td>
    </tr>    

    <tr align="center">
   <td></td>
   <td>
   <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>   
   <select name="id_lub" id="id_lub">
    <option value="">Nenhum</option>
    <?php
     $query = "SELECT * FROM lub ORDER BY lub";
     $result_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     while($row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query) ) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row_query['id_estoque'].'">'.$row_query['lub'].'</option>';
     }
    ?>
   </select>
   </td>
   <td class="td_preco>
   <span name="valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario"></span>
   </td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt7" id="qt7" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub7" id="sub7" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch7" value="ch7"></td>
    </tr>     
  </table>

<input name="total" id="total" readonly/>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor, não poste PHP em perguntas sobre JavaScript, isso só gera trabalho desnecessário para quem está tentando ajudar. Poste o HTML recebido pelo cliente, não o código fonte.

Comment: Ok. Pensei que ajudaria a entender a estrutura do meu site visualizar as id's que estou usando e etc., pq pode ser que haja erro em alguma coisa e por isso o JS não executa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer desta forma, criando 2 funções: uma que calcula os subtotais e outra que calcula o total. Crie também um event handler para disparar as funções quando alterar o checkbox e ao alterar o valor das quantidades, jogando a soma dos subtotais (apenas das linhas onde o checkbox está marcado) no campo `#total`:

```js
$(function(){
   
   function calcSub(linha){
      
      var preco = linha.find(".td_preco").text().trim() || 0;
      var quant = linha.find(".td_qt input").val() || 0;
      
      linha
      .find(".td_sub input")
      .val( linha.find(":checkbox").is(":checked") ? parseFloat(preco) * quant : '');

   }

   function calcTotal(){
      
      var total = 0;
      $("#table1 :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
         
         total += parseFloat($(this)
         .closest("tr")
         .find(".td_sub input")
         .val());
         
      });
      
      $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));

   }
   
   $("#table1 :checkbox, #table1 .td_qt input").on("click input", function(){
      calcSub($(this).closest("tr"));
      calcTotal();
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Preço</th>
   <th>Quantidade</th>
   <th>Subtotal</th>
   <th></th>
    </tr>
  
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query2['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco">5.18</td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt2" id="qt2" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub2" id="sub2" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch2" value="ch2"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query3['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco">2.00</td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt3" id="qt3" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub3" id="sub3" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch3" value="ch3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query4['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco">1.20</td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt4" id="qt4" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub4" id="sub4" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch4" value="ch4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query5['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco">1</td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt5" id="qt5" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub5" id="sub5" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch5" value="ch5"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
      <td></td>
   <td><?php echo $linha_query6['produto']; ?></td>
   <td class="td_preco">3.50</td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt6" id="qt6" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub6" id="sub6" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch6" value="ch6"></td>
    </tr>    

    <tr align="center">
   <td></td>
   <td>
   <span class="carregando">Aguarde, carregando...</span>   
   <select name="id_lub" id="id_lub">
    <option value="">Nenhum</option>
   </select>
   </td>
   <td class="td_preco">
   <span name="valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario"></span>
   </td>
   <td class="td_qt"><input name="qt7" id="qt7" value="1"/></td>
   <td class="td_sub"><input name="sub7" id="sub7" readonly/></td>
   <td class="td_ch"><input type="checkbox" name="ch7" value="ch7"></td>
    </tr>     
  </table>

<input name="total" id="total" readonly/>
```

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Esse 'handler' eu não conhecia. Vou estudar sobre.

Comment: Poderia tirar uma dúvida minha por favor, dentro desse código?
na parte:  $("#table1 :checkbox, #table1 .td_qt input")...
é para atualizar o subtotal, correto?
eu poderia adcionar: #table1 .td_select select, e funcionaria?

Comment: Creio que sim. Ele vai pegar o click no select. Tem que testar.